# Installation of python based website on Bluehost just not working

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, apache-http-server, python, putty

I have been at it for 6 months and I cannot get requests to respond on Bluehost shared server.  Here is my latest server code in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep

PORT_NUMBER = 8000

#This class will handle any incoming request from
#the browser
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    print "Something came through 1"

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        print "Something came through  2"
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/index.html"
        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path)
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return


        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)
            print '^C received, shutting down the web server'

try:

    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

I run the code and it appears to be running just fine... using Putty on the server side.

```
fakename@fakename.com [~/public_html]# python ps2.py
Started httpserver on port  8000
```

I fire up the site in Chrome and add this line to run a specific file:

```
http://fakedomain.com:8000/
```

or

it barks back at me with :

```
This site can’t be reached fakedomain.com.com took too long to respond.
Search Google for fakedomain com 8000
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

If I use PORT_NUMBER = 80  it barks back with :

```
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

If I use PORT_NUMBER = 8080  it barks back with :

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

The running Python's path is fine, it fires up just fine from anywhere and a version test gives this reply:

```
..........[~/public_html]# python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

Perhaps I need to do something else to stop the default server answering and allow my server to replace it...  I have no clue.  And I cannot find anything on the WEB to help me install it on BlueHost.  I have read some claims that BlueHost shared host does not work at all unless Django is used for Python.  I do not want to use Django...

Comment: Is it shared hosting or VPS? Do you have root access to the server? It looks like some other web service is taking over the port 80 and 8080, and doing internal reverse proxy. There might be nginx running on it.

Comment: I am not able to get BlueHost to respond.  They just don't want to give support on why ports 80 and 8080 give me that error.  My doing it on my own interferes with their peddling of WordPress.  So, their answer is just "Use WordPress".   I decided to build my own server instead.  Thank you for the advice...